# constraint parameter with key of an instance

Tags: typescript

Given an Actions object,

```
const Actions = {
  action1: {id: 1,name: "AD",points: 0},
  action2: {id: 3,name: "AD",points: 0},
  action3: {id: 4,name: "AD",points: 0},
}
```

I want to declare doSomething() as an async function where action is constrained to the keys of actions. I tried keyof Actions but it complains of being an instance type.

```
const doSomethng = async (action, value) => { ... }
```

Is it possible to restrict action (and get intellisense) as one of "action1", "action2" or "action3"

Comment: Try `action: keyof typeof Actions`

Comment: I tried this but it shows string|number as type

Comment: [Here's an example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6&jsx=0&strict=true#code/AQYw9gdgzgLsCCIYEtJWAXmAbwFDAMOAEMlUIBGALm2QBMqKAaCYgWwFMqAieAEW5MADmGQQYUKgAYAvk3xECpFJABMNelQDMLdl14Dho8ZNnzFSspC0aGAFl2ce-QSLETpchQRm5voNDg6MABlME4YAAsIAHNMEigATwgQYAAKZXIqYABrDkSwADNgGEShDiKEK2gmYAA3YgAbAFcOAEpMAD4cGSA)

Comment: Thanks Nadia. If you start typing "doSomething(" the context IDE popup lists many items along with "action1","action3" and "action3". Usually, I find TS to only recommend specific values satisfying the constraint. Is it a bug in TS to show so many other options or there's better way to see only the 3 values as in my example

Comment: doSomething(' when you add quotes it will pop up for suggestion as one of the actions